# I am not able to achieve the blur effect in swift

Tags: swift

I am not able to achieve the appropriate blur effect as per design in swift.

My code to add blur effect -

```
func addBlur() {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurredEffectView.alpha = 0.75
    imgView.alpha = 0.75
    blurredEffectView.frame = imgView.bounds
    imgView.subviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    imgView.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
    imgView.bringSubviewToFront(blurredEffectView)
}
```

Code to remove blur effect. -

```
func removeBlur() {
    for subview in imgView.subviews {
        if subview is UIVisualEffectView {
            imgView.alpha = 1
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the design -

[Desin blur effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud86B.png)

The one I achieve by my code -

[Achieved screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAGJD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not recommend to change the `alpha` property of a [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview) and is probably why you are not seeing the blur.

> **Setting the Correct Alpha Value**
>
> When using the UIVisualEffectView
> class, avoid alpha values that are less than 1. Creating views that
> are partially transparent causes the system to combine the view and
> all the associated subviews during an offscreen render pass.
> UIVisualEffectView objects need to be combined as part of the content
> they are layered on top of in order to look correct. Setting the alpha
> to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews
> causes many effects to

So remove this line `blurredEffectView.alpha = 0.75`

If you want to change the density / brightness of the blur, experiment with different [styles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiblureffect/style) `UIBlurEffect` has to offer and use the one that comes closest to your needs.

**Update**

If you do not get the desired results from `UIVisualEffectView`, you might look at [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifilter) which might give you more options with more control on the properties.

Here is an example of [CIFilter's gaussian blur](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifilter/3228331-gaussianblurfilter) and if you scroll down you can see some other options

Comment: Ok thanks @shawn But None of the styles are like my design. Is there a way around or is it we can only stick with styles that are provided?

Comment: @SabazShereefNerappoyil - see my update with an alternative using CIFilters

Answer (score 1):

@shawn-frank is right and I want to share one cool article about blur, in this article there is third (alternative) way with Metal.

[Different ways to creat blur](https://betterprogramming.pub/three-approaches-to-apply-blur-effect-in-ios-c1c941d862c3)

*Can not comment that why added answer*

Comment: Actually your article also adds a third way which I was not aware of before using Metal so it can still be a relevant answer / alternative. Maybe just edit your answer a bit to mention that this is a 3rd option to blur and I think it can also be a good valid alternative. Nice find !